# Cannot access properties of subclass

Tags: objective-c, subclass

I have created the following subclass to do some custom drawing:

```
//  DocumentIconView.h

@interface DocumentIconView : UIView
{
    UIImageView     *documentIconView;
    CloseHandle     *closeHandle;
    UILabel         *filenameLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *documentIconView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CloseHandle *closeHandle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *filenameLabel;

+ (DocumentIconView *)documentIconWithFrame:(CGRect)viewFrame
                     previewImage:(UIImage *)previewImage
                            title:(NSString *)title;
```

This works well for the most part (I can instantiate objects, and do custom drawing), however, I cannot access some of its properties from another classes.

```
DocumentIconView *iconView = [DocumentIconView documentIconWithFrame:frame 
                                                      previewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GenericDocumentIcon.png"] 
                                                             title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]];

iconView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];  // this works
iconView.filenameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; // this does not work - no error message
[documentsView addSubview:iconView];
```

I can read and write first-level properties, but cannot drill deeper; when trying to read properties, the value returned is `(null)`

I am fairly new at subclassing, so I think I am missing something really obvious here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: the method for instantiating the view in question:

```
+ (DocumentIconView *)documentIconWithFrame:(CGRect)viewFrame
                     previewImage:(UIImage *)previewImage
                            title:(NSString *)title
{
    DocumentIconView *view = [[DocumentIconView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];

    // Close handle's size is assigned here
    CGSize closeHandleSize = CGSizeMake(27, 27);

    // The document preview image's frame is calculated by shrinking it by the close handle's size
    CGRect documentPreviewFrame = CGRectMake(closeHandleSize.width / 2, 
                                           closeHandleSize.height / 2, 
                                           viewFrame.size.width - closeHandleSize.width, 
                                             viewFrame.size.height - closeHandleSize.height - 20); // 20 points is the filenameLabel's height

    UIImageView *documentPreviewView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:documentPreviewFrame];
    documentPreviewView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    documentPreviewView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    documentPreviewView.image = previewImage;

    [view addSubview:documentPreviewView];

    CGRect closeHandleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, closeHandleSize.width, closeHandleSize.height);
    CloseHandle *closeHandleView = [[CloseHandle alloc] initWithFrame:closeHandleFrame];

    closeHandleView.alpha = 0.0;
    closeHandleView.tag = kCloseHandleTag;
    [view addSubview:closeHandleView];

    CGRect filenameFrame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                      viewFrame.size.height - 20, 
                                      viewFrame.size.width, 
                                      20);
    UILabel *filenameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:filenameFrame];
    filenameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    filenameLabel.text = title;
    filenameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    filenameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    filenameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
    [view addSubview:filenameLabel];

    view.tag = kDocumentIconTag;

    return view;
}
```

Comment: [iconView.filenameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not with _that_ method. None of the properties can be accessed/modified.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *documentIconView; change to retain all of them

Comment: I am using Automatic Reference Counting, thus retain is no longer applicable. The object is retained by the strong attribute – and in the next line I can still work with the same object.

Comment: Any chance you can try separating the line into two statements, or putting in logs? E.g., `UILabel *label = iconView.filenameLabel; NSLog(@"%@, %@", label, label.backgroundColor); label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];` Let us know what you get. Also, any more information about how exactly you're instantiating the label? Seeing that line in your initializer would help.

Comment: Also, from my experience, I don't think ARC is completely ready for prime time yet. I had to take a recent project off of ARC because it simply was not behaving correctly; until I have more information, I'm going to assume that the problem is coming from the fact that your `filenameLabel` has been released for whatever reason by ARC, and you can no longer access it (perhaps `UILabel` is not yet fully ARC-compliant).

Comment: @Itai I broke the line into separate statements as you suggested, the result is the same: (null), (null). No error message.
To be clear, this problem not only affects the label, instead, all the other subviews as well. I can access and modify the iconView's properties, but nothing of its 3 subviews.

Comment: Well, here's the thing. If it's printing `(null), (null)`, it means the `filenameLabel` is `nil`, which is why setting its properties doesn't work. The question is why. Any chance we can see the `documentIconWithFrame:previewImage:title:` code? (BTW, if it's `nil`, you can still use it 'correctly' — you don't get errors sending messages to `nil` — but you can't really do much with it.) Also, do you get anything running the static analyzer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `documentIconWithFrame:...` method you're using a local variable (`filenameLabel`) that you're adding to the view. That means your instance variable is never instantiated and is always `nil`.

Just change this:

```
UILabel *filenameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:filenameFrame];
```

to this:

```
filenameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:filenameFrame];
```

and the same for the other instance variables.

Comment: Wow. I totally overlooked that.. You are right, that is the problem.